# Sprite Kit low performance with multiple nodes in one location

Tags: ios, collision-detection, sprite-kit

I have set up a scene with 200 sprite nodes and place them randomly on the screen like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < bubbleCount; i++) {
    CGSize size = [self getRandomSize];
    SKSpriteNode *bubble = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:texture size:size];
    bubble.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
    bubble.position = [self getRandomPosition];
    bubble.name = BUBBLE;

    SKPhysicsBody *physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:size.width/2];
    physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
    physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
    physicsBody.categoryBitMask =  0;
    physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = 0;
    physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;

    bubble.physicsBody = physicsBody;

    [self addChild:bubble];
}
```

As long as nodes keep distance from each other I get stable 60 fps. When I apply force so that nodes start moving towards the center of the scene and overlap each other, performance decreases dramatically to 2-3 fps. I guess it is related to collision detection and not rendering (if I initialize physics body with bigger radius, performance is very low already at the beginning). I have set category, contact and collision masks to 0, but it does not help.

Comment: What device are you testing on? Did you try release build? 200 contacting bodies is certainly a stressful situation you'd want to avoid. The fewer bodies overlap the better. Not sure if setting the bit masks to 0 actually helps or not, but you might try giving each node a different (one of 32) category bits to see if that improves things.

Comment: I'm testing on iphone 4s. Tried both debug and release configurations and assigning nodes to different categories, doesn't seem to get better.

Comment: Are you testing on the simulator or on an actual device?

Comment: Simulator does slightly better job, but frame rate drops anyway.

Comment: I'm going through the exact same thing. My game usually has around 120 nodes, but only about 60 have physics bodies, and 59 of those don't interact with each other [ie. the level peices only interact with the player].

What I've noticed is that the faster my game runs, the fast I'm adding and removing nodes, the slower it runs. Also the closer my player is to the level nodes, the slower it runs.

Comment: Ok, so after debugging a bunch of values, I found out I was personally creating infinite nodes and not deleting them. So after a couple thousand nodes my game would start to crawl. I'm now deleting nodes when they go off screen and the game operates smoothly. So it seems my issue may have been different to yours. Still I sometimes lose frame even with only a couple hundred nodes, which is worrisome.

Comment: Upped this Question. Having similar problem. I am testing on iPhone4 (device), getting 10fps and lower at merely 40 nodes with collisions physics. Similar project in cocos2d has no problem in the same device. Pretty sure there is something we're missing here. Hope the gurus can help.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet may be to pre-render this scenario instead of forcing the iPhone to go through 200 bodies of collision detection, which will undoubtedly cause strain.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm pretty sure the processor on an iPhone 4s should be able to handle collision between 200 simple bodies. Sounds like a very small load, especially while there are very complex 3D games for iPhone.